# pass the value of image id to modal box submit script to update the image

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I have Modal Box Confirmation , When I Choose Specific Image I Want It To change by The New Image , Below Code Show When I Store The Value Of Image Id :

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo  '
    <img  id="'.$row['id'].'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" src = "data:image;base64,'.$row['image'].'" class="imageHieght modal-content imageStyle clickedImage w3-round-large w3-border" style="width:100%">
    <form method="post" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">               
    <button href="#" name="updateImage" type="button" class ="w3-button imageButtons w3-round-large" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" >change</button>                
    <button href="#" name="deleteImage" class ="w3-button imageButtons w3-round-large" onclick=\'return confirm("Are you sure ?");\'>Delete</button>
    <input type="hidden"  name="imageId" value='.$row['id'].' />
    </form>
    </div>';

    }
```

And Below Code For Update Image query :

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
        $image1 =addslashes($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name']);
        $name1 =addslashes($_FILES['image1']['name']);
        $image1= file_get_contents($image1);
        $image1= base64_encode($image1);
        $stmt = $con->prepare(" UPDATE images SET name = ? , image = ? , caption = ? WHERE id = ? ");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssi",$name1,$image1,$caption1,$id1);
        $caption1 = $_POST['imageComment1'];
        $id1 = $_POST['imageId'];
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        if ($result) {
            echo'<div class="w3-panel w3-green w3-large w3-card w3-center hideMessage">Done</div>';     
        } else {
            echo '<div class="w3-panel w3-red w3-large w3-card w3-center hideMessage">try again</div>';   
       } 
   $stmt->close();
}
```

The Problem Is In $id1 Because When I Give The Id Directly It's Work But When I Use $_POST['imageId'] It's Now Working , i hope i found the answer

The modal box code :

```
<div class="modal fade center" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">   
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form role="form" method="post" class="w3-center" 
  enctype="multipart/form-data">    
    <div class="form-group">   
    <input type="file"  id="image1" name="image1"/>
    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="imageComment1" 
    name="imageComment1" placeholder="" required> 
    </div>
    </div> 
    <button type="submit" name="submit1" id="save1" class="w3-button 
      imageButtons1 w3-round-large">save      
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
    </button>
   <button type="submit" class="w3-button imageButtons2 w3-red w3-round-
     large" data-dismiss="modal">
     cancel <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    </button>
    </form>      
    </div>        
   </div>
  </div>          
 </div>
```

Comment: can you please add your modal code?

Comment: ok i will edit the topic @Omi

Comment: there is no `imageId` input in your form , then how would you able to access     that variable. Just handle click event on change button and store that image id in hidden input of modal form

Comment: look the first code you will find it  <input type="hidden"  name="imageId" value='.$row['id'].' /> @Omi

Comment: but both form are different so it wont be accessible in your php code just try var_dump($_POST) and confirm `imageId` is present with value

Comment: yes i know they're from 2 different  form so i want to know how to pass it

Comment: check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have imageid input in your form. You need to add that in your modal form & assign value to that onclick of change.

First you need to replace you change button with this code:

I have added onclick event which will pass the id to jquery function & that ll change your hidden input value.

```
<button onclick="setImgid(' . $row['id'] . ')" href="#" name="updateImage" type="button" class ="w3-button imageButtons w3-round-large" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" >change</button>
```

Add jquery function in your script:

```
<script>
function setImgid(imgId) {
   $("#imageId").val(imgId);
}
</script>
```

Then add `<input type="hidden" id="imageId" name="imageId" />`in your modal form.

Note:`<input type="hidden"  name="imageId" value='.$row['id'].' />` you dont need this, you can remove if you are not using.

Whole code:

```
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo  '
<img  id="'.$row['id'].'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" src = "data:image;base64,'.$row['image'].'" class="imageHieght modal-content imageStyle clickedImage w3-round-large w3-border" style="width:100%">
<form method="post" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">               
<button onclick="setImgid(' . $row['id'] . ')" href="#" name="updateImage" type="button" class ="w3-button imageButtons w3-round-large" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" >change</button>               
<button href="#" name="deleteImage" class ="w3-button imageButtons w3-round-large" onclick=\'return confirm("Are you sure ?");\'>Delete</button>
<input type="hidden"  name="imageId" value='.$row['id'].' />
</form>
</div>';

}
```

The modal box code:

```
<div class="modal fade center" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">   
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form role="form" method="post" class="w3-center" 
  enctype="multipart/form-data">    
    <div class="form-group">   
    <input type="file"  id="image1" name="image1"/>
    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="imageComment1" 
    name="imageComment1" placeholder="" required> 
    </div>
    </div> 
    <input type="hidden" id="imageId" name="imageId" />
    <button type="submit" name="submit1" id="save1" class="w3-button 
      imageButtons1 w3-round-large">save      
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
    </button>
   <button type="submit" class="w3-button imageButtons2 w3-red w3-round-
     large" data-dismiss="modal">
     cancel <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    </button>
    </form>      
    </div>        
   </div>
  </div>          
 </div>
```

Comment: what about this line ? $id1 = $_POST['imageId'];

Comment: Welcome, go ahead

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is in..

```
<input type="hidden"  name="imageId" value='.$row['id'].' />
```

Here the resulting HTML IS..

```
<input type="hidden"  name="imageId" value=Id1 />
```

Which is wrong.

Try This

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo  '
<img  id="'.$row['id'].'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" src = "data:image;base64,'.$row['image'].'" class="imageHieght modal-content imageStyle clickedImage w3-round-large w3-border" style="width:100%">
<form method="post" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">               
<button href="#" name="updateImage" type="button" class ="w3-button imageButtons w3-round-large" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" >change</button>                
<button href="#" name="deleteImage" class ="w3-button imageButtons w3-round-large" onclick=\'return confirm("Are you sure ?");\'>Delete</button>
<input type="hidden"  name="imageId" value="'.$row['id'].'" />
</form>
</div>';

}
```